# Magento - Review helper

Tags: magento, helper, review

I'm trying to instantiate the review helper class but failing..
I need to access getReviewsSummaryHtml() of class Mage_Review_Block_Product_View (app/code/code/Mage/Review/Block/Product/View.php).

I've tried this:

```
Mage::helper('review/product')->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true);
```

But I receive Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Review_Helper_Product' not found.

What am I doing wrong?

(p.s. I can't use $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml as $this is out of scope.)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `getReviewsSummaryHtml()` is defined in `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View`. You can instantiate it anywhere using `Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('review/product_view',$product);`. In order for this to work, though, you'll need to also have a block instance named `product_review_list.count`, which is normally defined in `review.xml`, is of type `core/template`, and uses the `review/product/view/count.phtml` template.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply do :

```
Mage::helper('review')
```

in order to get helper class which is named as Data.php

The function getReviewsSummaryHtml() resides in a block and you should only be able to call that function (ideally) from you template.

If you have moved that function to helper than you can call it like :

```
Mage::helper('review')->getReviewsSummaryHtml();
```

and you should do all these changes in your local.